# Create a SQL Server view using a table that have records that don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a view in SQL Server using a table that has a list of values that I want to join quite a few other columns onto it from other tables.

Any record that has values for every one of my "key" values works without problem, but when I want to add in a table that doesn't have records for every single "key" value, it just excludes that value. I want it to set it to `<NULL>` instead of just excluding it completely.

```
+--------+--------+--------+    
| KeyNum | Value1 | Value2 |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 988    | 14     | YES    |
| 989    | 44     | NO     |
| 778    | 124    | NO     |
| 445    | 87     | YES    |
| 999    | 12     | YES    |
| 368    | 89     | NO     |
+--------+--------+--------+

+--------+--------+
| KeyNum | Value5 |
+--------+--------+
| 988    | 88     |
| 989    | 12     |
| 999    | 74     |
| 368    | 46     |
+--------+--------+
```

So, what I want to do is join the values from the second table to the first one in a View, but when I try to, I can only get it to show values with records in the second table.

Comment: Sounds like you need an outer join instead of an inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to use left outer join instead of inner join
For example, when you want to display all the values from table1 and any matching rows from table2:

```
select a.*, b.value5 from table1 a
left outer join table2 b on a.keynum = b.keynum
```

Comment: Can you use joins when creating a view?

Comment: @LiveTangent Yes

Comment: One more question: If "table b" has multiple records that match the "KeyNum", is there a way to add them to a different column in the view, instead of adding new rows with "KeyNum"?

Comment: @LiveTangent: No. Well yes obviously there exists many ways to achieve this - but they are not out of the box solutions. The complexity increases significantly if you need to achieve this functionality. The phenomenon you mention with multiple records is called One-to-Many relationships.